# Integrating Bootstrap elements together on one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a Bootstrap site and am having a little trouble intergrating a jQuery Sortable Grid. I have included my source code in file clients.html and the plugin i'm trying to include in file plugin.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link href="assets/ico/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/0.3.0/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="favicon icon">
    <script src="javascript/jquery.gridly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="stylesheets/jquery.gridly.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar visible-phone" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></a> <a class="btn btn-navbar slide_menu_left visible-tablet"><span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
                    <div class="top-menu visible-desktop">
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li>
                                <a data-notification="2" href="#" id="messages"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Messages</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-notification="3" href="#" id="notifications"><i class="icon-globe"></i> Notifications</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-menu visible-phone visible-tablet">
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="link to View all Messages page, no popover in phone view or tablet"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="link to View all Notifications page, no popover in phone view or tablet"><i class="icon-globe"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html"><i class="icon-off"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Side menu -->
        <div class="sidebar-nav nav-collapse collapse">
            <div class="user_side clearfix">
                <img alt="Plush Management" src="assets/img/contact-icon.png">
                <h5>User</h5><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Settings</a>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle active b_F79999" href="index.html"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle b_F5C294" href="clients.html"><em class="icon-user"></em> <span>Clients</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle b_F6F1A2" href="tasks.html"><i class="icon-tasks"></i> <span>Tasks</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle b_C1F8A9" href="analytics.html"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> <span>Analytics</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle b_9FDDF6" href="tickets.html"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> <span>Support Tickets</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /Side menu -->
        <!-- Main window -->
        <div class="main_container" id="dashboard_page">
            <div class="row-fluid"></div>
            <div class="widget widget-padding">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                    <h5>Monthly Summary</h5>
                </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                <div class="widget widget-padding">
                    <div class="overview_boxes">
                        <div class="box_row clearfix">
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-eye-open" style="color:#E28271"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#E28271">+85%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-height="120" data-readonly="true" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="85">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>+530</strong>Pickups/Dropoffs</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-user" style="color:#98E5EA"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#98E5EA">+13%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-height="120" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="13">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>57</strong>Receiving</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-user" style="color:#98E5EA"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#98E5EA">+13%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-height="120" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="13">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>57</strong>Receiving</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-bullhorn" style="color:#AEEA98"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#AEEA98">+15%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-displayinput="false" data-height="120" data-readonly="true" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="15">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>35/235</strong>Deliveries</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="box_row clearfix">
                                <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                    <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                        <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                        <div class="white">
                                            <i class="icon-thumbs-up" style="color:#98AEEA"></i>
                                            <p style="color:#98AEEA">+55%</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input class="knob" data-displayinput="false" data-height="120" data-readonly="true" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="55">
                                        </div>
                                        <p><strong>$14,230</strong>Full Installs</p></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-credit-card" style="color:#EA98AB"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#EA98AB">+35%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-displayinput="false" data-height="120" data-readonly="true" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="35">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>152</strong>New Clients</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                            <div class="widget-tasks-statistics">
                                <div class="userstats clearfix" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <a data-target="#example_modal2" data-toggle="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <div class="white">
                                        <i class="icon-phone" style="color:#F6BF99"></i>
                                        <p style="color:#F6BF99">+97%</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="knob" data-displayinput="false" data-height="120" data-readonly="true" data-thickness=".15" data-width="120" value="97">
                                    </div>
                                    <p><strong>592</strong>Consults</p></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
            <div class="widget widget-padding">
                <div class="widget-header">
                    <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>
                    <h5>Client Management</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="widget widget-padding span12">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="widget-body">
                                    <div class="widget-forms clearfix">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Quick Search <em class="icon-caret-down"></em></a> <input class="span7" data-items="4" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[&quot;Alabama&quot;,&quot;Alaska&quot;,&quot;Arizona&quot;,&quot;Arkansas&quot;,&quot;California&quot;,&quot;Colorado&quot;,&quot;Connecticut&quot;,&quot;Delaware&quot;,&quot;Florida&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Hawaii&quot;,&quot;Idaho&quot;,&quot;Illinois&quot;,&quot;Indiana&quot;,&quot;Iowa&quot;,&quot;Kansas&quot;,&quot;Kentucky&quot;,&quot;Louisiana&quot;,&quot;Maine&quot;,&quot;Maryland&quot;,&quot;Massachusetts&quot;,&quot;Michigan&quot;,&quot;Minnesota&quot;,&quot;Mississippi&quot;,&quot;Missouri&quot;,&quot;Montana&quot;,&quot;Nebraska&quot;,&quot;Nevada&quot;,&quot;New Hampshire&quot;,&quot;New Jersey&quot;,&quot;New Mexico&quot;,&quot;New York&quot;,&quot;North Dakota&quot;,&quot;North Carolina&quot;,&quot;Ohio&quot;,&quot;Oklahoma&quot;,&quot;Oregon&quot;,&quot;Pennsylvania&quot;,&quot;Rhode Island&quot;,&quot;South Carolina&quot;,&quot;South Dakota&quot;,&quot;Tennessee&quot;,&quot;Texas&quot;,&quot;Utah&quot;,&quot;Vermont&quot;,&quot;Virginia&quot;,&quot;Washington&quot;,&quot;West Virginia&quot;,&quot;Wisconsin&quot;,&quot;Wyoming&quot;]" placeholder="Type here for auto complete…" style="margin: 0 auto;" type="text">
                                                    <ul aria-labelledby="dLabel" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">Clients</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#">Customers</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="controls"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                                                <a class="btn btn-small btn-box bubble bubble-danger span2 tips" href="new_client.html"><em class="icon-user"></em><span>Add New Client</span></a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-box span2" href="#"><em class="icon-map-marker"></em><span>Delivery Requests</span></a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-box bubble bubble-info span2 tips" href="#"><em class="icon-thumbs-up"></em><span>Whiteboard</span></a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-box bubble bubble-info span2 tips" href="#"><em class="icon-twitter"></em><span>Invoice Manager</span></a> <a class="btn btn-small btn-box bubble bubble-warning span2 tips" href="#"><em class="icon-globe"></em><span>Region</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /Main window -->
                            </div><!--/.fluid-container-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- ===========================================================================================-->
            <div class="row-fluid"></div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="widget widget-padding span12">
                    <div class="widget-header">
                        <i class="icon-group"></i>
                        <h5>Delivery Requests</h5>
                        <div class="widget-buttons">
                            <a class="tip collapse" data-collapsed="false" data-title="Collapse" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="users">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Request Date</th>
                                    <th>Client</th>
                                    <th>Item</th>
                                    <th>Images</th>
                                    <th>Location</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                    <td>Admin</td>
                                    <td>20-05-2012</td>
                                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Email</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Katy</td>
                                    <td>User</td>
                                    <td>12-08-2012</td>
                                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Email</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Serena</td>
                                    <td>User</td>
                                    <td>05-01-2013</td>
                                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Email</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div><!-- /widget-body -->
                </div><!-- /widget -->
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="widget widget-padding span12">
                    <div class="widget-header">
                        <i class="icon-group"></i>
                        <h5>Invoice Manager</h5>
                        <div class="widget-buttons">
                            <a class="tip collapse" data-collapsed="false" data-title="Collapse" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="users">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Invoice #</th>
                                    <th>Invoice Date</th>
                                    <th>Client</th>
                                    <th>Customer</th>
                                    <th>Invoice Type</th>
                                    <th>Sub-Total</th>
                                    <th>Paid</th>
                                    <th>Balance Due</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                    <td>Admin</td>
                                    <td>20-05-2012</td>
                                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Email</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                    <td>Amie</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div><!-- /widget-body -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- /widget -->


                    </div><!-- /widget-body -->
                </div><!-- /widget -->

            <!-- wrap ends-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src='assets/js/sparkline.js' type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src='assets/js/morris.min.js' type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.facybox.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src='assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
            </script> 
            <script src='assets/js/jquery.gritter.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/realm.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="assets/js/tiny.editor.packed.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Also the Jquery plugin can be found here: https://github.com/ksylvest/jquery-gridly

Comment: Let's see the code then.

Comment: you can find my site here http://plushadmin.com/clients.html and the plugin here http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/?utm_source=jquer.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation

Comment: Being equally lazy, any console log errors you're getting?

Comment: nothing that will point out why it isnt working.

Comment: PS I'm really new at hmtl and css. But have coding experience.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library into your source? It'd be nice if you could take some time to paste the related source code of your clients.html file in the question. I know you've posted a link to your website, but doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: Please include code here, not on some other site. Other links can change or disappear over time, making the question useless. Also you're making the volunteers on this site work harder for no reason, and that's not in your interest! Post only what is relevant to reproduce the issue (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance). BTW, the specific issue is not clear. We need a bit more detail than "having trouble". Explain what is going wrong, exactly.

Comment: NO! include in your question, please, not as comment. edit the question and add it. thanks

Comment: @ADyson, you can always view page source

Comment: Code in Question

Comment: anybody? or should i close this?

Comment: @TomasAVazquez view source of what? I don't get you. And you still haven't explained what "having trouble" means. Explain your issue clearly. If I asked you to fix my car and you said what's wrong, and I said "I'm having trouble", you would ask me to clarify. Same thing applies here. Give us a clue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to load the Gridly library after jQuery, you're currently loading it before hand. If Gridly relies on any jQuery dependency, it likely will not work if it's loaded before.

You need to  move this line (from the header):

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.gridly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To under this line (in the footer):

```
<script src="assets/js/tiny.editor.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once you've done that, your Gridly library should work.